# Counting files (image) and log into a file

Tags: shell-script, find

```
find JPG -type f -iname '*.jpg' | wc -l >> PictureCount.md
```

I am trying to count the number image files by extension and have it write to a file, like a list. This doesnt work for what Im trying to do, the .md is empty and running the .sh just hangs up

Comment: And ... what happens instead? How is that wrong?

Comment: Welcome! What seems to be the problem? Assuming you want to count files/pictures inside JPG folder, it should work. But you probably want a different outcome? We need to know, so we can help.

Comment: it does not list in the file. it does nothing. Im listing 3 types of image extensions in the file (or trying to)

Comment: Is `JPG` a directory containing the files you want to count? If so, your command is correct (within the constraints you've described).

Comment: This question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59346343/error-for-picture-already-exist-and-not-printing-results-of-my-count-to-a-file), although no feedback provided.

Comment: I had an issue with posting the code and used images (noob here)

Comment: @MrClick Noobs are welcome. Learners try to improve, edit and respond or delete a question if it became obsolete 

Answer (score 0):

On a GNU system, to count the number of each type of image file, relying on the `file` utility to determine the type instead of the extension, you could do something like:

```
(export LC_ALL=C
find . -type f -exec file -0NF ''  --mime-type {} + |
  sed -nz '1d; s/^ //; s/\n.*//; s|^image/||p' |
  sort -z |
  uniq -cz |
  sort -zrn |
  tr '\0' '\n')
```

Which would output something like:

```
    272 gif
     87 x-ms-bmp
     84 png
     55 jpeg
      2 x-xpmi
      1 wmf
```

Comment: Does this put the list into a specific file? I am trying to count .jpg, .png, and .tiff files in folders and send that list to my .md file

Comment: @MrClick this outputs into whatever file is open on stout.  Use redirection  to output it somewhere else

Comment: I'll give it try and thank you